# HTML and JavaScript in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp, model-view-controller

So i have made a simple 3 page site in html and JavaScript. Now im wanting to put it in a cakephp framework and am totally lost. The site is a simpe home page, create user screen and onmouseover game thing.

Comment: based on which version of cakephp you want to use the [documentation](http://cakephp.org/pages/documentation) should help.

Answer (score 2):

Can i ask you a question? What is the extra value of using a framework on a 3 page based website? And from where are you lost? Already installed Cake?

And if you want to know a little bit more about CakePHP, i really suggest you to read the documentation 2.x and follow the tutorial of making a blog with CakePHP.

It will learn you all the basic things of Cake and you only need like an hour to practice.

Like;

- How to make a login and registration page, and more

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html

Thats my advice to you.

Comment: Well i need a MVC architecture so thought id just nab one with good documentation etc. Cakes installed sweet and im ready to go. Question is where do i start? M, V or C? Ill been looking at and will continue to read through the documentation. Cheers for your reply!

Comment: Well i suppose you already know where the letters stands for, how i always start with cakephp ( in the beginning ) with the C (Controller) Because if you start with that one, you can follow the errors as steps, it wil say you need a V (View) with a name like this, you need a M (Model) with a name like this... etc

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to understand MVC with that being said a sample controller would be as follows under cakephp 2.x
under App/Controller a simple controller:

SamplesController.php with a similar build

```
class SamplesController extends AppController {
   // Consider these functions pages
   function pageA(){ 

   }
   function pageB(){

   }
   function pageC(){

   }
}
```

Navigate to App/View create folder Samples. In there create `pageA.ctp`, `pageB.ctp` and `pageC.ctp` . [the ctp files are your pages or proper term view. ]

copy your data of the 3 page site in each ctp file. and your done just navigate to the respected url. `http://localhost/cakephpbuild/samples/pageA` <= Example only

Comment: Thats a great place to start. My final question for now is around a simple model. Im also trying to get picture links working between the pages?

Comment: technically, the views should be labelled `page_a.ctp`, `page_b.ctp` ... http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#view-conventions